# Find maximum after multiplying two columns from two different tables - SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the right way to find the maximum after multiplying 2 columns in different tables:
Orders `(OID, PID, Quantity, Date)`
Products `(PID, Pname, Price, Category, Subcategory)`.
I need to find which OID has the highest total order amount.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT OID, OrderAmount
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderAmount=(SELECT MAX(OrderAmount) from Orders
(SELECT Orders.OID, OrderAmount=Products.Price*Orders.Quantity
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.PID=Products.PID);
```

Maybe there is a more effective solution?
Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Use inner join then group by then top statement, in single select statement no need for any sub query

Comment: select top 1 max(Products.Price*Orders.Quantity) as TOrderAmount, Orders.OID 
from Orders
INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.PID=Products.PID
group by Orders.OID order by TOrderAmount desc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: `Aggregate` function

```
SELECT TOP 1 OID, MAX(OrderAmount) MaxOrderAmount
FROM (
       SELECT Orders.OID, OrderAmount = Products.Price * Orders.Quantity
       FROM Orders INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.PID=Products.PID
     ) X GROUP BY OID
```

Method 1: `Row_Number` Concept

```
SELECT TOP 1 OID, OrderAmount AS MaxOrderAmount
FROM (
       SELECT Orders.OID, OrderAmount = Products.Price * Orders.Quantity
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Products.Price * Orders.Quantity) RN
       FROM Orders INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.PID=Products.PID
     ) X WHERE RN = 1
```